# Filter collection using parent's property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to apply a filter on a collection (SET) using a property in the parent's class.
I've found out that I can use the `where` clause for a collection - and it seems to work - but I am not sure if this is the best option or if this solution could give me pains in the future.

[image]

This is the mapping for my class `Order`:

```
<class name="Order" table="OCSAORH_NHBP" mutable="false" where="OCHAMND = 0">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="Number" column="OCHORDN" type="String" length="10"></key-property>
      <key-property name="Ver" column="OCHAMND" type="Int32"></key-property>
      <key-property name="Company" column="OCHCOSC" type="String" length="5"></key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="WareHouseDelivery" column="OCHMAGS" type="String" length="7"></property>

    <set name="OrderLines" access="field.pascalcase-underscore" inverse="true" lazy="true" mutable="false" cascade="none" where="OCLMAGS = this_.OCHMAGS">
      <key>
        <column name="OCLORDN" not-null="true"/>
        <column name="OCLAMND" not-null="true"/> 
        <column name="OCLCOSC" not-null="true"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="OrderLine" not-found ="ignore" />
    </set>
</class>
```

and this is my class `OrderLine` :

```
<class name="OrderLine" table="OCSALIN_NHBP" mutable="false" where="OCLAMND = 0">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="Number" column="OCLORDN" type="String" length="10"></key-property>
      <key-property name="Company" column="OCLCOSC" type="String" length="5"></key-property>
      <key-property name="Line" column="OCLLINN" type="Int32"></key-property>
      <key-property name="Seq" column="OCLSSEQ" type="Int32"></key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Item" column="OCLITMN" type="String" length="19"></property>
    <property name="WareHouseDelivery" column="OCLMAGS" type="String" length="7"></property>

    <many-to-one name="Order" class="Order">
      <column name="OCLORDN" not-null="true"/>
      <column name="OCLAMND" not-null="true"/>
      <column name="OCLCOSC" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

This is a Oracle legacy database and I cannot change it's schema. Primary keys are all composite.

Now, I would like to fetch the orders using some criteria and lazy-load the order lines using, as a filter, the field **OCHMAGS** (property WareHouseDelivery).
As you can see I've defined a `where` clause in the set using the alias of the parent's table :

```
<set name="OrderLines" ... where="OCLMAGS = this_.OCHMAGS">
```

PS: I eager-load my orderlines collection:

```
var qry = .QueryOver<Domain.Order>()
    .Fetch(t => t.OrderLines).Eager
    .JoinAlias(t => t.OrderLines, () => orderLine, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

Is this a viable solution? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your comment: *... and it seems to work ...*
Because it cannot work. The `this` representing the `Parent`, is not available in the WHERE clause of the collection mapping. It is the alias of the collection table.

The collection is loaded separately from the owner. NHibernate will execute the `SELECT...FROM` the `OrderLine` table: "OCSALIN_NHBP". Without any JOIN to the parent. As a parameter in the WHERE clause is injected the `ParentId` (in your case, the key is composed from more columns). That's it.

One way how to do that, is to create more complex WHERE clause, using the `Parent` Table as subselect. *(This is of course not so effective on large tables)*

```
  <set ...
    where="OCLMAGS IN 
      (SELECT p.OCLMAGS FROM OCSAORH_NHBP p WHERE p.OCLORDN = OCLORDN...)" >
```

Maybe there are even other ways, but the `this` is not what it seems to be

Comment: Radim, thanks for your help. I've updated my question with some more info (see the picture and the c# QueryOver) and it does work. Of course it is a trick.

Comment: Do you think I should use [filters](http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters) ?

Comment: The porblem with a *filter* is, that it is "ISession" based. So, it is not related to parent. I am using filter, and it is doing great job, if I want to filter elements based on for example culture. Then I set the filter: Culture == "cs" and only items, wiht this condition are selected. What we need here, is (I would say) a bit different. We need to filter by some property of the parent, which could be (on the list) different for each Parent. So, this could work for selecting only one Parent record, and his collection. I know, not as good answer as could be...

Comment: I've just read your update. In this case, it could work, but it is dangerous, if someone else, will execute different query, without eager loading. But in case, that the eager is there... On the other hand, I would say, that the best would be to step our for a while. Try to think, if you cannot somehow place a marker (IsActive) in the Order item table... and then the WHERE caluse will work